# C# Regular Expression - Does not seem to work consistently

Tags: c#, regex

The Microsoft .NET C# regular expression:

```
@"^(t4_(?:[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9])_(?:2?[0-3]{2}|1?[0-9])[jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec]{3}(?:[0-9]{4}))_([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{4})_([comp|disk|scs]){4}\\b";
```

The (filenames that I wish to search for are consistently named as follows:

```
TraceLog_somename_other.log          -- should not match
t4_systx2_03oct2021_0001_2359_comp   -- Match
t4_systx2_03oct2021_0001_2359_disk   -- Match
t4_systx2_03oct2021_0001_2359_scs    -- does not match
```

The goal is to scan a directory via a regular express "mask" of files of a specific filename signature.  The signature used is the same for all files. It seems to attempt to match to a pattern is one way to do this.

Why would this not work? If there is a better way to accomplish this... thanks for sharing?

Thanks!

Tim P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are asking why this does not match:

```
t4_systx2_03oct2021_0001_2359_scs
```

The problem is with this part of your regex:

```
([comp|disk|scs]){4}
```

This is looking for exactly four occurrences of any characters in the set `comp|disk|scs`. This might match the ending `comp`, but it could just as easily match the ending `cccc`, `ksid`, `scss`, etc.

Try this instead:

```
(comp|disk|scs)
```

As @41686d6564 points out in the comments, you have the same problem with the pattern you use to match months. Instead of `[jan|feb|...]{3}`, use `(jan|feb|...)`.

Full regex:

```
^(t4_(?:[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9])_(?:2?[0-3]{2}|1?[0-9])(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)(?:[0-9]{4}))_([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{4})_(comp|disk|scs)\b
```

Comment: Same goes for `[jan|feb|...]`.

Comment: Interesting - I removed the {} from the string for [jan|feb|...] and [comp | disk ... ] and still no match.  Your comment clarified what was happening - which enabled me to solve the issue - Thanks!  I changed the expression and now the string matches for 3 and 4 alpha patterns correctly:  ````^(t4_(?:[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9])_(?:2?[0-3]{2}|1?[0-9])[jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec]{3}(?:[0-9]{4}))_([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{4})_(?:([comp|disk]{4})|([scs]{3}))\b````

Comment: That regex still doesn't look right to me. It will match months like `aaa` and endings like `ccc` (because you are using `[`] and `]`). Is that what you intend?

Comment: This is what I finally ended up with: '''@"^(t4_((?:[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]))_((?:2?[0-9]{2}|1?[0-9])[jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec]{3}(?:[0-9]{4}))_([0-9]{4}))_([0-9]{4})_(?:([a-z]{3})|([a-z]{4})|([a-z]{5})|([a-z]{6})|([a-z]{7})|([a-z]{8})|([a-z]{9}))\b";''' -- It is possible the match in the 6th group may be any alpha combination of 3-9 characters. The Regex seems to work with the all cases that I tested... To your question, the date format that needed to be pattern matched is nnmmmYYYY - though it is a mangled mess, I didn't know better way to handle the date. thanks!